# The package product 'MyLibrary' cannot be used as a dependency of this target because it uses unsafe build flags

Tags: ios, macos, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to add SPM support for my library. I need to define `unsafeFlags` for one of my library's targets (In order to import Swift code into Objective-C++):

```swift
.target(name: "MyLibrary",
        dependencies: ["MyOtherTarget"],
        cSettings: [
            .unsafeFlags(["-fmodules", "-fcxx-modules"]),
            .define("BUILDING_FOR_SPM")
        ]
),
```

The resulting package builds. But when I import it into a host app, it fails to build because

```
The package product 'MyLibrary' cannot be used as a dependency of this target because it uses unsafe build flags.
```

According to [this post](https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0238-package-manager-target-specific-build-settings/18341/10) and the corresponding [pull request](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/pull/2254), the issue was addressed in Swift 4. I'm using Xcode 12.5 and Swift 5.

So what's going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.unsafeFlags` are not allowed for dependencies specified with a version. The workaround is to specify the version with a commit hash.

Detailed discussion and another workaround for monorepos at https://forums.swift.org/t/override-for-unsafeflags-in-swift-package-manager/45273

Comment: Worth mentioning that you should clean the project before recompiling again with the commit hash option.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue where our own package was failing to resolve:

> xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
> the target '_a_target_A' in product '_a_product' contains unsafe build flags
> the target '_a_target_B' in product '_a_product' contains unsafe build flags

The solution was to define the exact revision of the package to pull in:

```
.package(
  url: "https://...@dev.azure.com/.../OurProject/_git/OurOwnPackageName",
  revision: ".....complete_hash_of_version_commit......"
)
```